# Python 3: Pass variable from one CLASS to another

Tags: python-3.x, oop, instantiation

I have a beginner problem here. I have a parent Class that contains a call to SQLite DB and to ConfigParser ini file and I want my child Class to access all those pieces of information.

Below is my code and what I've tried so far with no success. I understand instantiation but only with minimal examples like employees/salaries lol.

My code works if I copy all the calls to DB and config files into the child Class and it's not how it should be done, I know. Could you please help me?

```
class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.wxFont = "9, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL"

        path =os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        configFile = os.path.join(path , "config.ini")

        dbfile = os.path.join(path , "report.db")
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
        self.theCursor =  self.db_conn.cursor()

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(configFile)


        if config.get('Network', 'taboola') == "true" and config.get('Network', 'outbrain') == "true":
            network = ""
        elif config.get('Network', 'taboola') == "true" and config.get('Network', 'outbrain') == "false":
            network = " and CAMPAIGN LIKE '%TB%'"
        elif config.get('Network', 'outbrain') == "true" and config.get('Network', 'taboola') == "false":
            network = " and CAMPAIGN LIKE '%OB%'"
        else:
            network = ""

        if config.get('Sort', 'value') == "Impr.":
            sort = "IMPR" 
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "Clicks":
            sort = "CLICKS"
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "CTR":
            sort = "CTR"  
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "CPC":
            sort = "CPC"  
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "eCPC":
            sort = "eCPC"
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "Spent":
            sort = "SPENT"
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "Revenue":
            sort = "GA_REV" 
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "GA Impr.":
            sort = "GA_IMPR"  
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "GA Clicks":
            sort = "GA_CLICKS"
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "GA CTR":
            sort = "GA_CTR"
        elif config.get('Sort', 'value') == "Rev. /1000":
            sort = "GA_RPM"
        else:
            sort = "SPENT"

        #['Impr.', 'Clicks', 'CTR', 'CPC', 'eCPC', 'Spent', 'Revenue', 'GA Impr.', 'GA Clicks', 'GA CTR', 'Rev. /1000'] 

        if config.get('Filter', 'column') == "Campaign":
            column = "CAMPAIGN"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "Impr.":
            column = "IMPR"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "Clicks":
            column = "CLICKS"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "CTR":
            column = "CTR" 
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "CPC":
            column = "CPC"  
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "eCPC":
            column = "eCPC"    
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "Spent":
            column = "SPENT"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "Revenue":
            column = "GA_REV" 
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "GA Impr.":
            column = "GA_IMPR"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "GA Clicks":
            column = "GA_CLICKS"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "GA CTR":
            column = "GA_CTR"        
        elif config.get('Filter', 'column') == "Rev. /1000":
            column = "GA_RPM"
        else:
            column = ""

        if config.get('Filter', 'operator') == "Contains":
            query = "and " + column + " LIKE '%" + config.get('Filter', 'string') + "%'"
        elif config.get('Filter', 'operator') == "Doesn't Contain":
            query = "and " + column + " NOT LIKE '%" + config.get('Filter', 'string') + "%'"


        if config.get('Filter', 'operator') == "<":
            query = "and " + column + " < " + config.get('Filter', 'string')
        elif config.get('Filter', 'operator') == ">":
            query = "and " + column + " > " + config.get('Filter', 'string')

        #To instantiate
        queryFiltre = "SELECT * FROM Report WHERE  GA_RPM > 0 " + query + network + "  and STATUS = '1' ORDER BY " + sort + " DESC"
        print(queryFiltre) 

        rows = self.db_conn.execute(queryFiltre)
        rowsCount = len(rows.fetchall())

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "V1.0", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)
```

What I've done so far:

```
class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)


        self.wxFont = "9, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL"
        self.queryFiltre = ""

        def setQueryFiltre(queryFiltre):
            path =os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            configFile = os.path.join(path , "config.ini")
            dbfile = os.path.join(path , "report.db")
            self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
            self.theCursor =  self.db_conn.cursor()

            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config.read(configFile)

            #All the calls to DB and config file here

            return queryFiltre

        def getQueryFiltre(queryFiltre):
            queryFiltre = queryFiltre

        rows = db_conn.execute(queryFiltre)
        rowsCount = len(rows.fetchall())


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "V1.0", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)

        self.wxFont = SimpleGrid(self.wxFont)
        self.queryFiltre = SimpleGrid.getQueryFiltre()
```

But here the first error I get is the db_conn is not defined and I'm sure I will still have more to handel if this one is taken car of. In fact all the variables within the def setQueryFiltre should be accessible from within both the parent and the child Classes.

Thank you,

EDIT:

With oe without self. i still get the same error
[image]

Comment: You definitely need `self.` for referencing db_conn, since you declared it as a member variable. `rows = db_conn.execute(queryFiltre)` should be `rows = self.db_conn.execute(queryFiltre)`.

Comment: With .self or without I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Can you copy the complete error stack trace? It will have line numbers.

Comment: Also, you never call `setQueryFiltre` function you declare, so none of that code gets executed. Is there any reason you declare it inside constructor rather than its own method? Nesting functions like that is sort of an anti-pattern.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error. What do you mean by call setQueryFiltre?

Comment: `def setQueryFiltre(args)` declares the function, you then execute it by calling `setQueryFiltre(args)`.

Comment: The original example works better they execute the logic, you never call the function, therefore db_conn never gets appended to self.

Comment: Yea, I think you meant to declare those two functions as methods, not as nested functions

Comment: I've called the setQuetFiltre and it seems to have passed through the db_conn error, now it's the path (that is called elsewhere) that is causing the error not defined. How should I go about all the variables in my setQueryFiltre method?

Comment: See updated answer, your issue seems to be indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared 2 functions inside your constructor, which never get called: `setQueryFiltre` and `getQueryFiltre`. Moreover, your test calls one of them as if it was a class method. It's not, and it will fail becuase that declaration is only visible inside the function. What you probably meant to write is this:

```
class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.setQueryFiltre(None)

        self.wxFont = "9, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL"
        self.queryFiltre = ""

    def setQueryFiltre(self, queryFiltre):
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        configFile = os.path.join(path , "config.ini")
        dbfile = os.path.join(path , "report.db")
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
        self.theCursor =  self.db_conn.cursor()

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(configFile)

        #All the calls to DB and config file here
        return queryFiltre # why are you returning the argument? For chaining?

    def getQueryFiltre(self, queryFiltre):
        queryFiltre = queryFiltre

        rows = self.db_conn.execute(queryFiltre)
        rowsCount = len(rows.fetchall())
        # you probably want to return rows here?


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "V1.0", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)

        # self.wxFont = SimpleGrid(self.wxFont) # what does this try to do?
        self.queryFiltre = self.grid.getQueryFiltre()
```

In Python, indentation is important.

Note that I also moved db initialization to constructor, where it belongs. Because otherwise, if get method gets called before set, you will still have the same crash. I also made a couple other comments that you'll probably get bitten by next.

Comment: I've already tried and I got "'SimpleGrid' object has no attribute 'db_conn'"

Comment: Nvm, I thought the bottom part was inheriting from the top. It's not clear from your question that the bottom is your implementation of the version from the top. The problem is you never declared it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my code, sorry but that part was cut as I thought it was clear that all that is cut from the code above will still exist in the code below. I've only added what was modified.

Comment: No those 2 lines have to be executed inside the parent Class. I've added self to the path and it seems to be solved. Now it the call to wxfont and queryfiltre that seem to be causing this error : type object 'SimpleGrid' has no attribute 'getQueryFiltre'

Comment: Moving the db init will rise an error because dbfile is defined after. I think my problem is in the instantiation in the child class.

Comment: All member variables should be defined in the constructor (at least to sane defaults, which you can update later) unless you want to get bitten by bugs like this in the future. Why is your setQueryFiltre separated from your constructor? It doesn't do anything with the argument passed in and all the declarations in it are hardcoded - so putting them in constructor (__init__) would be better anyway.

Comment: The setQueryFiltre  is in the constructor (see the code in my question) something may went wrong with your copy-paste. When you say to define all the variables in the constructor, you mean all those used in the setQueryFiltre define? I'm pretty noob to Python so all this is not clear in y head as I'm still learning :(

Comment: self.grid.getQueryFiltre() is not working too. Error:'SimpleGrid' object has no attribute 'getQueryFiltre'

Comment: It still never gets called. A function won't just call itself because it's declared. Also get declared inside constructor will never be visible to the outside.

Comment: I hear you, but how to call it and where? I thought it was called in the child Class here: self.queryFiltre = self.grid.getQueryFiltre(). Sorry for the thumb questions. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: See updated answer, you can call it from anywhere but by calling it from constructor I ensured that constructor sets all these variables.

Comment: Nothing is working. I'm sorry but I quit. I've really no idea what I'm doing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194278/discussion-between-alexander-tsepkov-and-creek-barbara).